# Match words that are not inside the characters < > using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match words that are not inside `<` `>`.

This is the regular expression for matching words inside `<` `>`:

```
text = " Hi <how> is <everything> going"
pattern_neg =  r'<([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)>'
m = re.findall(pattern_neg, text)

# m is ['how', 'everything']
```

I want the result to be `['Hi', 'is', 'going']`.

Comment: Words "Hi", "is" and "going", sorry

Comment: Will there _always_ be spaces before the `<` and after the `>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression approach:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"\b(?<!<)\w+(?!>)\b", text)
['Hi', 'is', 'going']
```

Where `\b` are the word boundaries, `(?<!<)` is a negative lookbehind and `(?!>)` a negative lookahead, `\w+` would match one or more alphanumeric characters.

A non-regex naive approach (splitting by space, checking if each word not starts with `<` and not ends with `>`):

```
>>> [word for word in text.split() if not word.startswith("<") and not word.endswith(">")]
['Hi', 'is', 'going']
```

---

To also handle the `<hello how> are you` case, we would need something different:

```
>>> text = " Hi <how> is <everything> going"
>>> re.findall(r"(?:^|\s)(?!<)([\w\s]+)(?!>)(?:\s|$)", text)
[' Hi', 'is', 'going']
>>> text = "<hello how> are you"
>>> re.findall(r"(?:^|\s)(?!<)([\w\s]+)(?!>)(?:\s|$)", text)
['are you']
```

Note that `are you` now have to be splitted to get individual words.

Comment: Just FYI, `<` and `>` have no special meaning, and don't need to be escaped.

Comment: what if i have white spaces between words inside <>, for instance,               "<hello how> are you" and I would like to extract "are" and "you"?

Comment: oh, doc = "<hello how> are you"
match = re.findall(r"\b(?!\<)\w+(?!\>)\b", doc), this extracts ['hello', 'are', 'you']

Comment: @Inigo okay, please see the update. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Inigo thanks, I still have a strong feeling that there is an easier and better way.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

text = " Hi <how> is <everything> going"
[s.strip() for s in re.split('\s*<.*?>\s*', text)]
>> ['Hi', 'is', 'going']
```